# How to spectate Battlefield 1 operation on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, battlefield-1

I found that I can spectate via server browser on server info page, but not sure how to spectate operation, since there are no operations in the browser. Sometimes operation server shows number of spectators, so it seems to be possible.